# .load() function won't load javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, load

When I use the function `.load()`, it will load the page that I want to load in the `div` that is selected.

But when I want to use JavaScript/jQuery that I already have coded in other files, it wont work anymore.

It does work when I just `include '';` the page static in the `div`.

Does anyone have an idea why this works like this?

Static:

```
<div id="loginCont" class="modal-body">
    <?php
    include 'login.php';
    ?>
</div>
```

by Javascript/jQuery

```
$("#memberFalse").on("click", function() {
    $('#loginCont').load("/213server/_inc/login.php");
});
```

Comment: May be path not taking correctly. `.load("/213server/_inc/login.php");`

Comment: when building the page do both the selectors get their respective elements correctly? try log their size.

Comment: does `#memberFalse` exists before you want to add the clickhandler? where is the js located?Is it in `$(document).ready(..` or after the `#memberFalse` element

Comment: What's the javascript in the .php that you're loading?  If it's some sort of `document.ready()` then that would explain it.

Comment: Please post the include() that works.

Comment: Remember that include() starts from the root of your server, and load() starts from the root of your WEB server.

Comment: @morels what do you mean, can you give a example?

Comment: @swidmann Yes it does, all my `.js` files are loaded at the bottom of my `body` ;)

Comment: @freedomn-m its not clear to me what you mean. :s

Comment: @Webomatik I think you make a twist? As I knew, it was `include()` is from root of the web and `load()` from the server...? :s

Comment: @Webomatik Can you put it as answer? For who needs it as well, and you will get points ;) ;p

Comment: @Lenap `console.log($("#memberFalse").size());` logs 0 or 1 ? and `$("#memberFalse").on("click", function() {
    console.log($('#loginCont').size()); });` logs 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Can you post the complete path to where the DIV with ID "loginCont" is located. Your load() function should fetch from that location.

Comment: php include that starts with "/" refers to the root of the server. Load() starting with "/" starts at the root of the web server. Javascript (or jQuery) has no access outside the web root.

Answer (score 1):

A PHP include that starts with "/" refers to the root of the server, unless specified otherwise in your php.ini file. Your code:

```
<div id="loginCont" class="modal-body">
  <?php
  include 'login.php';
  ?>
</div>
```

fetches "login.php" from the folder where the current page is located. You can display that location with:

```
<?php echo __DIR__  ?>
```

Your jQuery load() method should fetch the page "login.php" from that location too. There is obviously a mistake in the following path:

```
$('#loginCont').load("/213server/_inc/login.php");
```

Remember that Javascript/jQuery CANNOT fetch files outside the web root, but PHP can. For example, if your login.php file is located at "/var/_inc/login.php" and your web root is at "/var/www/", jQuery will never have access to login.php. If your login.php file is located at "/var/www/myproject/_inc/login.php", then your load() function should fetch it like this:

```
$('#loginCont').load("/myproject/_inc/login.php");
```